# I need to secure my node js website to HTTPS running on the default 80 port of HTTP

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, server, ssl-certificate

I am running my server on ionos hosting and executing nodejs on the default port of 80.
I don't know how to enable the HTTPS for it.
Following is my sample node js server creation code:

```
const Https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const httpsServer = Https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync("private.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("Dev-2020-09-12-013930.cer")
}, app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(Https);

global.SOCKET = io;
const ip = require('ip');
console.log('websocket server start.' + ' ipaddress = ' + ip.address() );

// const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
httpsServer.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('Server port: ' + port);
});
```

I have generated certificates and added them. On running the server it gives message of server started but does not load on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines of code and see if you get "Hello" text in your browser.

```js
https.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello");
});
```

if that didn't work try doing it this way

```js
httpsServer.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello");
});
```

**EDIT**

Check out the official documentation https://nodejs.org/api/https.html

Comment: Rerunning the server , on the console it gives server initiated . But does not run anything when trying to run from browser

Comment: Have you deployed it to your platform? Certificates won't work for localhost.

Comment: yes, it is on live platform, I want to enable the HTTPS on my IP

Comment: I suggest to check out this link. https://nodejs.org/api/https.html